# Print vtbl functions of any class in GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

Newer version of gdb allow for convenient parsing of vtables in C++.

Say I have this sample code

```
class Matcher {
public:
    virtual void match() { cout << "base";}
};

class NMatcher: public Matcher{
public:
    void match() { cout << "derived";}
};

int main() {
    Matcher* m = new Matcher();
    m->match();

    Matcher *m2 = new NMatcher();
    m2->match();
}
```

I can access the virtual table of both variables present in main via `info vtbl ...`

```
(gdb) info vtbl m
vtable for 'Matcher' @ 0x400ef0 (subobject @ 0x603010):
[0]: 0x400d9a <Matcher::match()>
```

Now imagine a situation where I have no variable in scope and I would like to inspect the vtable of any virtual object (or any pure virtual base class). For that I do not strictly need an object. The vtable is static and should be accessible.

Let's look at the symbols to locate the vtable:

```
(gdb) info variables .*Matcher
All variables matching regular expression ".*Matcher":

Non-debugging symbols:
0x0000000000400ec0  vtable for NMatcher
0x0000000000400ee0  vtable for Matcher
0x0000000000400ef8  typeinfo name for NMatcher
0x0000000000400f10  typeinfo for NMatcher
0x0000000000400f28  typeinfo name for Matcher
0x0000000000400f40  typeinfo for Matcher
```

I can not use the listed memory location above directly. The virtual methods do not start at the beginning of the vtable. There is offset and RTI present for the first x bytes. In case of matcher it is 16, but it can be any arbitrary number:

```
(gdb) p *m
$22 = {
   _vptr.Matcher = 0x400ef0 <vtable for Matcher+16>
}
```

In theory I can access the memory location of the vtable directly and inspect the bytes manually:

```
(gdb) x /4a 0x0000000000400ee0
0x400ee0 <_ZTV7Matcher>:    0x0 0x400f40 <_ZTI7Matcher>
0x400ef0 <_ZTV7Matcher+16>: 0x400d9a <Matcher::match()>
```

But that is too painful and I would like to know a convenient way of doing something along the lines of `(gdb) info vtbl 'vtable for Matcher'`

I am using GDB 7.8 but any version will do.

Answer (score 5):

GDB doesn't provide a built-in way to do this, I'm afraid.

You could maybe approximate it with a hack.  The hack would work like this:

- Get the base address of the vtable, like `print &'vtable for Type'`.
- Get the base address of the typeinfo for the type, like `print &'typeinfo for Type'`.
- Search through the vtable word-by-word, looking for a pointer to the typeinfo.  The next word is the where a vtable pointer should point.
- Now, make a dummy object with this as a vtable pointer.

However, this isn't going to work if you have a sub-object vtable.  In that case you'd have to make a phony object that is more correct.

On the whole it would be better to add this support to gdb.  It could try to do the right thing without hacks.

Here's how this works for your program above:

```
(gdb) p &'vtable for NMatcher'
$1 = (<data variable, no debug info> *) 0x400ab0 <vtable for NMatcher>
(gdb) p &'typeinfo for NMatcher'
$2 = (<data variable, no debug info> *) 0x400ae0 <typeinfo for NMatcher>
```

Now dump the vtable and see where the pointer should be.  It's the second word here because there are no virtual bases:

```
(gdb) x/10a $1
0x400ab0 <_ZTV8NMatcher>:   0x0 0x400ae0 <_ZTI8NMatcher>
0x400ac0 <_ZTV8NMatcher+16>:    0x4009b2 <NMatcher::match()>    0x0
0x400ad0 <_ZTV7Matcher+8>:  0x400b08 <_ZTI7Matcher> 0x400994 <Matcher::match()>
0x400ae0 <_ZTI8NMatcher>:   0x6011e0 <_ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE@@CXXABI_1.3+16>  0x400af8 <_ZTS8NMatcher>
0x400af0 <_ZTI8NMatcher+16>:    0x400b08 <_ZTI7Matcher> 0x65686374614d4e38
```

So, make a phony object.  Unfortunately you need the inferior running to do this :-(

```
(gdb) set $v = malloc(sizeof(void*))
```

Set the fake vtable pointer.  Note we use one word after the pointer to the typeinfo object:

```
(gdb) set *$v = ((void **) $1) + 2
```

Now it works:

```
(gdb) info vtbl (NMatcher*) $v
vtable for 'NMatcher' @ 0x400ac0 (subobject @ 0x613c20):
[0]: 0x4009b2 <NMatcher::match()>
```